# PHP fb api get secret group information without user login

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am a member of a secret group and want to access and use the groups information within an  php-website. Is it possible to access secret groups without an enduser-login? Is there a way to add the app as group-member or set "special" privileges? I don't want to set the group to a public one, because the members shouldn't be public.

```
require "api/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    // try to fetch all events - error no user token provided
$ret = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/xxx/events?access_token=$access_token");
```

Result:

```
{
   "error": {
   "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
   "type": "OAuthException",
   "code": 102
   }
}
```

`getAccessToken` returns an App-Token, but I need an user token. AFAIK I need an user login for an user token - right?

Comment: thx. would accept this as an answer - please create one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a security issue if this was allowed. You should not be able to access a private group information without login. Think about the other groups that you are not a member of that you would be able to access. You NEED to do oauth to get access to private groups. and the user logged in must be part of that group